# convert decimal number including decimal point to binary number in java

Tags: java

//I want to make a program to make binary number using the following programs.
//But I can use only  "for" and "if" .

```
public class Name {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double x =Math.PI-3;
        int t;
        for(t=0;t<=19;t++){
            System.out.print(x+"\t");
            if(x<0.5){
               x=2*x;
           }
            else{
                x=2*x-1;
        }
            System.out.print(x);
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: So `1.2` is supposed to give what binary value?

Comment: You actually computing an `int` and printing it out at the end. Printing out the way you do means, the integer is _converted to signed decimal representation_. It is not the binary represenation, which you can print out using `Integer.toBinaryString(i)`.

Comment: (1.2)10=(1 . 0011 0011 0011 0011 0011 0011)2

Comment: Sorry,It wanted to say that I wanted to make the numerical value that appeared by the following programs binary number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the

```
 Integer.toBinaryString(number to convert)
```

or something like below code:

```
public void convertBinary(int num){
 int binary[] = new int[40];
 int index = 0;
 while(num > 0){
   binary[index++] = num%2;
   num = num/2;
 }

 for(int i = index-1;i >= 0;i--){
   System.out.print(binary[i]);
 }
```